# Query efficiency - which performs better?

Tags: sql, performance, hive, inner-join, where-clause

I'm wondering if someone can explain which (if any) of these queries is more efficient, or would they perform the same?

Any insight is appreciated.

Query #1:

```
select 
    col_1, col_2
from 
    tableA
join 
    (select 
         col_1, col_2
     from 
         tableB
     where 
         col_2 > X and col_2 < Y) subQueryB on tableA.col_1 = subQueryB.col_1
```

Query #2:

```
select 
    col_1, col_2
from  
    tableA
join 
    tableB on tableA.col_1 = tableB.col_1
where 
    tableB.col_2 > X and tableB.col_2 < Y
```

Comment: The queries seem ambiguous. Which table's `col_1` and `col_2` are being returned?

Comment: The best way to find out is to try it.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the configuration of table indexes, etc

But you can:

See what query is takinn more execution time...

Use EXPLAIN before each query to get the execution plan.